# laravel project deploy to Heroku but bootstrap styles missing

Tags: php, laravel, heroku

I deploy laravel project on  Heroku.

but bootstrap styles a missing.

bootstrap is in **public dir**

in browser network showing this

[image]
Showing status **blocked**

Comment: Can you share your blade file where you import the style/JS assets?

Comment: https://github.com/Ahmadkhan12345566/OnlineCourseRegistrationSystemLaravel/blob/master/resources/views/Home/index.blade.php

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are looking for [secure_asset](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/helpers#method-secure-asset)

> Generate a URL for an asset using HTTPS:

In your code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ secure_asset('css/AdminLTE.min.css') }}">
```

Comment: not working for me 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70939106/why-css-files-working-in-local-laravel-but-not-in-heroku

Answer (score 9):

Go to app >> Providers >> AppServiceProvider.php

Import this:

```php
use \Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL;
```

Under the boot method, paste the code below

```php
if ($this->app->environment('production')) {
    URL::forceScheme('https');
}
```

Note: The code above checks whether you are in development mode or production to render your assets.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following.

```
@production
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ secure_asset('css/AdminLTE.min.css') }}">
@endproduction
```

Answer (score 0):

Just Add the Following lines in **AppServiceProvide.php** inside **boot** function

```
if (env('APP_ENV') != 'local') {
            URL::forceScheme('https');
        }
```

This will automatically detect your current host and convert simple **HTTP** request to **HTTPS**. Hopefully it will work for you.