# Why css files working in local laravel but not in heroku?

Tags: php, laravel, heroku

I have Laravel app.

I am referencing a CSS file.

The file is inside a public folder, css app.

it is working fine locally when deploying to heroku, it says 404.

```
web: vendor/bin/heroku-php-apache2 public/
```

and my .htcsss

is

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/index.php?$1 [END,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

both in the root and under public folder.

I am loading my asset

```
  <link href="{{ secure_asset('/css/app/shopex.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="{{secure_asset('css/app/shopex.css')}}" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{secure_asset('css/app/shopex.css')}}" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{secure_asset('/css/app/shopex.css')}}" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{secure_asset('public/css/app/shopex.css')}}" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{secure_asset('/public/css/app/shopex.css')}}" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="public/css/app/shopex.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/public/css/app/shopex.css" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('css/app/shopex.css')}}" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('/css/app/shopex.css')}}" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('public/css/app/shopex.css')}}" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('/public/css/app/shopex.css')}}" />
```

Answer (score -1):

Hi try to remove first backslash from 'css/app/shopex.css' and check the ssl sertificate still alive on your heroku becouse secure_asset use The secure_asset function generates a URL for an asset using HTTPS.  Try to use asset becouse The asset function generates a URL for an asset using the current scheme of the request (HTTP or HTTPS):

Comment: not working bro\